# Colours relations in blender?

Tags: keyframes

So I was just wondering what all the colours mean in blender.
For example:
Yellow is keyframe relation?

[image: Yellow]

Green  is between  keyframes?
[image]

Also seen a purple coloured things, for the lack of a better word, can anyone point me to the wiki if possible and tell me the name of this phenomenon?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the themes section of user preferences. There you can not only find out what all the colors mean but also change them.
[image]

[image]